# How do I write a proper include and modulize my app in C?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

I am once again asking for your help :) Cannot find a mistake in #includes, checked several times, have compared with geekstogeeks example and similar question here. So I've got:

```
/tmp/ccWUaJkV.o:/home/felix/Programming/dypak/objects.obj:27: multiple definition of `RankNames'
/tmp/ccA7hhxl.o:/home/felix/Programming/dypak/objects.obj:27: first defined here
/tmp/ccWUaJkV.o:/home/felix/Programming/dypak/objects.obj:28: multiple definition of `SuitNames'
/tmp/ccA7hhxl.o:/home/felix/Programming/dypak/objects.obj:28: first defined here
/tmp/ccWUaJkV.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `__odr_asan.SuitNames'
/tmp/ccA7hhxl.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccWUaJkV.o:(.bss+0x1): multiple definition of `__odr_asan.RankNames'
/tmp/ccA7hhxl.o:(.bss+0x1): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After compiling with

```
gcc -rdynamic -std=c11 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` cardmethods.c main.c -o main `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lX11
```

## objects.obj

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#ifndef OBJECTS_O_
#define OBJECTS_O_

typedef struct myCard{
    bool trump;
    ...
} card;
typedef struct {
     ...
} widgetsPtrs;

card *Deck;//pointer to the deck.
/************************************HERE****************************/
char *RankNames[] = {"  6  ", "  7  ", "  8 ", ...};
char *SuitNames[] = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};

#endif
```

## cardmethods.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "objects.obj"

#ifndef CARDMETHODS_H_
#define CARDMETHODS_H_

void addCard(card *pile, card *cardAdded);
void printAll(card *pile);
...


#endif
```

## cardmethods.c

```
#include "cardmethods.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void addCard(card *pile, card *cardAdded){
    ...
}
void printAll(card *pile){
    ...
}
...
```

## main.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "cardmethods.h"

 ...

int main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot define `RankNames` and `SuitNames` multiply globally. If you want to use them as some kind of constants you might declare them `static` to restrict visibilty to the current translation unit and avoid the multiple definition errors. You should declare them `const`, too, then.

Comment: Note that the name `objects.obj` would be an object file on Windows systems.  Choose a different suffix, for the sake of the sanity of others even if not for your own.

Comment: When you use include guards, it is crucial that they are first and last in the header.  Other `#include` lines may follow the include guards; they should not precede them.  If you don't follow this rule, you can get into trouble with mutually recursive headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined the variables `RankNames` and `SuitNames` in your header file.  Because of this, they are defined in both main.c and cardmethods.c.  Then when these files are linked, the linker finds multiple definitions.

Change the header file to have external declarations of these variables (and `Deck`):

```
extern card *Deck;
extern char *RankNames[];
extern char *SuitNames[];
```

And put the definitions in *one* source file, probably cardmethods.c:

```
card *Deck;
char *RankNames[] = {"  6  ", "  7  ", "  8 ", ...};
char *SuitNames[] = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked perfectly. The problem was that I redefined the variables.